# Unable to get JSON Url Parameters in struts2

Tags: java, json, jqgrid, struts2

I am using JQgrid in my struts 2 web application .. When giving the JSON url TO the Grid I am passing parameters along with that action. Here is my code

```
<s:url var="jsonURL" action="JSONAction"  > 
    <s:param name="empID" value="%{empID_}" ></s:param>   
    <s:param name="DeptID" value="%{DeptID_}" ></s:param>   
</s:url>
```

I have created setters and Getters for those parameters in my Action class

My problem is I can get `empID` in my action class
But unable to get that second variable `DeptID` in my action class
 if I change the order of that i can get that `DeptID` value in my action class ...
I can get only one parameter in my action class ..

Comment: What is the url it generating?

Comment: just now I have resolved this by using `escapeAmp="false"` this option I think I am correct in dealing this ... Is there any security problem with this..?

Comment: This property is just used to parse parameter seperator (& operator / amp;). So whenever data is tansfered, it should be in proper format. I  think, this should not cause any security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<s:url var="jsonURL" action="JSONAction" escapeAmp="false" > 
    <s:param name="empID" value="%{empID_}" ></s:param>   
    <s:param name="DeptID" value="%{DeptID_}" ></s:param>   
</s:url>
```